# How to show same date on ui in Different TimeZone using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In DB I have date as 23-MAR-17. In EST the values show properly on UI. 
But when I change the timezone to Aisa/Kolkatta. I see the values as 22-MAR-17 on UI.

For the date conversion I have used Moment.js.

```
moment(dateString, format).format(COMMON.dateFormat)
```

How can i fix this Issue with moment.js.

Comment: Create a moment, set the timezone and then set the date

Comment: How do you change timezone? Note that by default moment parses string in local time.

Comment: I have rest services which give the date in miliseconds format and then by using moment.js i convert to date with a specific format.  On my local machine i change the windows timezone.  so by changing that i see diff date on the UI.